# How to repeat an item multiple times in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to place a star, ★, on a Web page, repeatedly. Is there a way to specify a symbol and how many times it should appear, in HTML or CSS? E.g., something like this, but not necessarily the same syntax, in which an item is specified, along with a quantity:

```
<repeat n="5">★</repeat>
```

This will result in:

```
★★★★★
```

Comment: What do you mean you want it to appear a certain number of times in CSS? Do you mean you want the actual symbol to appear on the webpage?

Comment: Yes, the symbol, or text, or other item should appear however many specified times, repeatedly on the page.

Answer (score 6):

You could place the star as a repeating background image of an element; and tweak the width of the element via CSS. Something like:

```css
.stars {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaEDC.png);
}
.stars-2 {
  width: 26px;
}
.stars-3 {
  width: 39px;
}
.stars-4 {
  width: 52px;
}
.stars-5 {
  width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<span class="stars"></span><br>
<span class="stars stars-2"></span><br>
<span class="stars stars-3"></span><br>
<span class="stars stars-4"></span><br>
<span class="stars stars-5"></span>
```

Comment: I mean using an image as `background` is not scalable on different sizes (specially for RWD).

Answer (score 5):

Use [content](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) property like this:

**Note:** that using *repeat* is not recommended in your case its not a valid html tag, use *div*, *span* or *a*.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v3A7j/)**

Use **SCSS** or **LESS** to generate style sheet like this.

**CSS:**

```
<style>
repeat {
    display:block;
}

repeat[n="1"]:before {
   content: "★";
}

repeat[n="2"]:before {
   content: "★★";
}

repeat[n="3"]:before {
   content: "★★★";
}

repeat[n="4"]:before {
   content: "★★★★";
}

repeat[n="5"]:before {
   content: "★★★★★";
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<repeat n="1"></repeat>
<repeat n="2"></repeat>
<repeat n="5"></repeat>
```

Comment: Use the `<span>` element instead. There's no `<repeat>` tag in HTML, unless you use JavaScript to create such an element in order to select that in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use jQuery (or just javascript but different code), you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[repeat]').each(function() {
     var toRepeat = $(this).text();
     var times = parseInt($(this).attr('repeat'));
     var repeated = Array(times+1).join(toRepeat);
     $(this).text(repeated).removeAttr('repeat');
   });
 });
```

Then when you have

```
<span repeat="5">★</span>
```

It will become

```
<span>★★★★★</span>
```

Comment: would be better to use data-repeat. repeat is not an allowed attribute

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
body{
 counter-reset: Counter;
}

sameTypeElement::after{
  counter-increment: Counter;
  content:counter(Counter) " ★";
}
```

or simpler:

```
sameTypeElement::after{
  content:'★';
}
```

sameTypeElement siblinging is unknown for different browsers, but must work with any level of nesting tiying to type of selector

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the star a certain number of times you can use JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.write("&#9733");
}
```

Will result in: `★★★★★`

If you want to be able to access a particular star, you will need to wrap each star in a span and give it a unique id:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  document.write("<span id=\"star" + i + "\">&#9733</span>");
}
```

This will result in:

```
<span class="star0">★</span>
<span class="star1">★</span>
<span class="star2">★</span>
<span class="star3">★</span>
<span class="star4">★</span>
```

Comment: `document.write` is a bad practice

Comment: merely a demonstration rather than an implementation suggestion