# How can I repeat CSS pseudo-element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have code:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height:100px;
}

div:before {
  content: 'sale';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I want to fill the div with pseudo-element:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  height: 100px;
}

div:before {
  content: 'sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale sale ';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Can I do this with something like *repeat-content*? I dont want to repeat the word manually and the div is responsive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repeat an item multiple times in HTML or CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376113/how-to-repeat-an-item-multiple-times-in-html-or-css)

Comment: You can't do this with `content: ...` and pure css.

Comment: @the4kman, No, Don't want to make the same, so I can have too many words, it is not only 5 stars. Read the question carefully before putting a minus sign! I am asking about multiple repetitions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as "repeat-content" or something similar in CSS. Your second snippet is the only way to achieve this effect now. Such repetition would be gzipped well, though.

In theory, there is the `element()` function in CSS that [makes it possible](http://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-element-function) to use one HTML element (but not pseudo element) as a background for another (including repeating background). Unfortunately, it is supported only in Firefox.