# How to "multiply" css elements?

Tags: html, css

I have some geometric shapes below the header to form a line.

[image: geometric shapes]

```
    <div class="linha_grafica_do_titulo">
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
        <figure class="linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas"></figure>
    </div>
```

```
    .linha_grafica_do_titulo {
      display: flex;
      gap: 10px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-direction: row;
    
    }
    
    .linha_grafica_do_titulo__caixas {
      width: 30px;
      height: 50px;
      -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
      background-color: #ff003c;
    }
```

This doesn't seem like the best way to go about it. Is there a way to do this without repeating so many tags?

Honestly I don't know how to do this. I think maybe I could use a different tag for this or do some sort of attribute multiplication.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376113/how-to-repeat-an-item-multiple-times-in-html-or-css

Answer (score 3):

No need to duplicate (or even add) extra child elements. This could be achieved with a [repeating-linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/repeating-linear-gradient).

So with only this html

```
<div class="linha_grafica_do_titulo"><div>
```

We only need this css

```
.linha_grafica_do_titulo {
  height: 50px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    110deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 10px,
    #ff003c 10px,
    #ff003c 40px
  );
}
```

A bit of explanation

- A repeating background gradients orientation is left to right by default, so we need to rotate it 90deg for top/down + 20deg for the skew u want (results in 110deg).
- 10px is the equivalent of the `gap` property u used for the child elements.
- 40px is the gap (10px) + the width (40px) of your stripes.

If we want, we can use css variables to make it easier to adjust / play around with.

```
.linha_grafica_do_titulo {
  --line-color: #ff003c;
  --line-width: 30px;
  --line-gap: 10px;
  
  height: 50px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    110deg,
    transparent,
    transparent var(--line-gap),
    var(--line-color) var(--line-gap),
    var(--line-color) calc(var(--line-gap) + var(--line-width))
  );
}
```

You can check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdt2nzpv/) for the result.